# Calling a date in a function works if the date is written "yyyy-mm-dd" but not in a variable that is written as x <- "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: r, function, date, for-loop

I'm using a function from the climateR package to get a lot of precipitation data. The function I'm using is `getLOCA()` from this package: https://rdrr.io/github/mikejohnson51/climateR/f/README.md

I run into memory errors if I try to run the function for all of the data at once, so I'm writing a loop to take each year individually, 1950-2099, going through several models. The function is as follows:

`getLOCA(AOI, param, model = "modelname", scenario = "scenarioname", startDate = "yyyy-mm-dd", endDate = "yyyy-mm-dd")`

The issue I'm running into is trying to use a variable for the startDate and endDate. I have it set up right now using it like this:

```
for (iyear in 1950:2099){
date_start <- paste0(iyear,"-01-01")
date_end <- paste0(iyear,"-12-31")
getLOCA(AOI, param, model = "modelname", scenario = "scenarioname", startDate = date_start, endDate = date_end)
}
```

But it's coming back with the following error:

**Error in var[[i]] * scale_factor :
non-numeric argument to binary operator**

What am I doing wrong? When I run the function manually and input the dates in the format specified, it works. Then setting that exact thing into a variable itself and it comes up with an error. Why does it work when I use the date inputted manually but won't take it from a variable?

Comment: Try: Wrap your `paste0.....)` command for `date_start` and `date_end` with `date_start <- as.Date(paste0(iyear,"-01-01")` and same with `date_end` in your for loop.

Comment: Do you get this error for each instance or is it a specific date that is causing the problem?

Comment: Each instance. Whenever I try it manually putting a date in it works fine, but using the same date put into a variable it won't work anymore. It's like this with every date I've tried.

Comment: Odd, does it work putting the paste directly in the function `getLOCA(AOI, param, model = "modelname", scenario = "scenarioname", startDate = paste0(iyear,"-01-01"), endDate = paste0(iyear,"-12-31"))`?

Comment: Right? I feel like the answer should be simple but nothing I've tried is working. Putting it in directly to the function comes up with the same error still. :(

Comment: Yeah that's unfortunate. Apologies, but without a reproducible example that produces the error it's difficult to help beyond speculation.

Comment: For some reason, adding another set of parentheses around the paste0 made it work! not sure why but adding it into the function directly within another set of parentheses did it. Thanks everyone for the help!